# Authentication error "The UserNameOrEmailAddress field is required"

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, abp

The last few days I have been busy making a project in ABP, yesterday I spent the whole day working on it and everything was up and running when I went home. Today I started up the project (from another location) and now I get this pop-up window error when logging in:

> The UserNameOrEmailAddress field is required.

I checked in the console and it gave 2 errors:

> POST http://localhost:21021/api/TokenAuth/Authenticate 400 (Bad Request)

and:

> ERROR Error: An unexpected server error occurred.
>       at new SwaggerException (service-proxies.ts:4308)
>       at throwException (service-proxies.ts:4328)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.project (service-proxies.ts:1618)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext
>   (mergeMap.js:60)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._next
>   (mergeMap.js:50)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next
>   (Subscriber.js:54)
>       at Observable._subscribe (service-proxies.ts:4334)
>       at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe
>   (Observable.js:42)
>       at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe
>   (Observable.js:28)
>       at MergeMapOperator.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapOperator.call
>   (mergeMap.js:28)

I am logging in with the proper credentials and if I run the authenticate method with those same credentials on Swagger UI I get a **200 OK** response. Perhaps this has something to do with me running the program on a different location?

Comment: If you have relevant code, can you show us?

Comment: The whole login and authorization system is included in the template I used, I didnt change any of these things so I don't really have any relevant code to show

Comment: For some reason its fixed now, I had to restart the computer for something else and when it restarted I first ran the Web.Host project from within Visual studio and then used `npm start` and now it does work.